# Keeping Position with Jquery draggable box

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, coordinates

I have been trying to make a jquery draggable text box and it worked successfully and now I am trying to get the text box to remember the coordinates of its last position. I have searched high and low. I found some examples but they never worked. So when I place the text box some where on the page and I refresh the page I want it to be in the location it was last in. The code I will be providing you below is the one where every time you refresh it returns to the original position. Can anyone help?

Here is the code.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Something</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
  <style>
  #draggable { width: 75px; height: 50px; padding: 0.25em; }
  </style>
  <script>
  $(function() {
  $('#draggable').draggable(
    {
        drag: function(){
            var offset = $(this).offset();
            var xPos = offset.left;
            var yPos = offset.top;
            $('#posX').text('x: ' + xPos);
            $('#posY').text('y: ' + yPos);
        }
    });

  });
  </script>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
  <style>
  #test { width: 75px; height: 50px; padding: 0.25em; }
  </style>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#test" ).draggable();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>Test</p>
</div>
<div id="test" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>Test</p>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: How are you refreshing the page? If you refresh it with the browser (F5) is not possible without save the position somewhere (session, db, other) because the page is fully reloaded

Comment: Okay then how do i create a session to save its position?

Comment: It depends on your server side language; you can communicate via ajax and set/get your element position or use a simple cookie instead; in a few I give you an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you refresh your page with the browser (F5) is not possible restore the position of elemente without save the position somewhere (session, db, cookies, local storage, other) because the page is fully reloaded.

For example you can simply use the [`jquery.cookie`](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) plugin to set/get a cookie containing the position of the dragged div:

```
  $('#draggable').draggable({
      drag: function () {
          var cookie_value = JSON.stringify($(this).offset());
          $.cookie('newPosition', cookie_value, {
              expires: 7
          });
      }
  });

  if ($.cookie('newPosition')) {
      //console.log($.cookie('newPosition'))
      $("#draggable").offset({
          top: JSON.parse($.cookie('newPosition')).top,
          left: JSON.parse($.cookie('newPosition')).left
      })
  }
```

or calling get/set webmethods to handle the position with jQuery.ajax

Here is a working fiddle using cookies: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/pqhQu/

Comment: Can this ``jquery.cookie`` remember the position until the user re-login? Do we have to store it in the database to do so?

Comment: It depends, a cookie is stored in the local machine and can be used to save options and data, but they are not per user. If you want to store data across local machines or this settings is a true applicative data you have to store it on DB.

Comment: Could I have the full code please. I am having trouble putting it in. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Sorry my bad. I was confused but now i get it